# Manually setting Jmeter home directory

Tags: jmeter

According to [this post](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Automatic-generation-of-aggregate-reports-td4281459.html), the Jmeter home is automatically detected. Is there a way to manually set this? 
My scripts starts java from another place, causing the home to be incorrectly detected.

Comment: any feedback on this ? you should accept it if it's ok for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line option :

- -d {argument}
- or --homedir {argument}

  the jmeter home directory to use

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

Comment: I found an awfully hacky workaround to what I wanted, but I will try your answer and let you know, Thanks!

Comment: A quick tip: if you have more than one version installed, including one from a repo in linux, the -d command not not work.  Make sure to use the dot slash convention $ ./jmeter arg0, arg1, arg2...  as when I didn't, the "main" directory was used instead of the alternate downloaded one that was my pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter 4, If you want to run command out side of the bin folder, you have to decleare `jmeter` home in path. and it should be `C:\apache-jmeter-4.0`, `"apache-jmeter-4.0"` this folder containing all folder including bin.