# Jmeter failed to start with the Prometheus JMX agent when run not from $JMETER_HOME/bin

Tags: java, jmeter, prometheus, jmx

Trying configure Prometheus JMX agent for Jmeter but faced following issue - when I start Jmeter outside of **$JMETER_HOME/bin** folder - it fails with an error:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access null/lib
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:105)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access null/lib/ext
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:105)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access null/lib/junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:105)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:250)
JMeter home directory was detected as: null
```

Launch command:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12021 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12021 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true -javaagent:/apps/injector/apache-jmeter/bin/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.13.0.jar=8778:/apps/injector/apache-jmeter/bin/prometheus_config.yaml -jar /apps/injector/apache-jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t /apps/injector/apache-jmeter/extras/Test.jmx
```

Same command works fine in case I run it from **$JMETER_HOME/bin** folder.
It's not seems to be a Jmeter issue itself, as I can run same command from any place, and it will not cause an error in case I remove **-javaagent** option.

Can somebody help me configure Prometheus JMX agent for properly work with Jmeter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually setting Jmeter home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271830/manually-setting-jmeter-home-directory)

Comment: I have defined JMETER_HOME and have JMETER_HOME and JMETER_HOME/bin within the PATH, otherwise I wouldn't be able to run raw Jmeter outside of it's bin folder.
However this doesn't help when it comes to javaagent usage...
Btw - I've tried other agents some time ago, and there were no issues with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to java options of JMeter:

> -Djmeter.home=$JMETER_HOME

As per your bugzilla ticket:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64680

Credit to Felix S. member of JMeter team